# cannot convert 'char (*)[30]' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'int search(char*, char*)'

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
char name[100][30];
char author[100][30];
char publisher[100][30];
int in_out[100];
int i=0;
int dumpnumber;

void add_book();
int search_book();
void printing(int id_print);
int search(char *text1, char *text2);

int search_book(){
    int select_search;  
    char dumpchar[30];

    printf("1. Title to search : ");
    printf("2. Author to search : ");
    printf("3. Name to search : ");
    printf("Now What do you want ? : ");
    scanf("%d", &select_search);
    if(select_search==1){

        printf("Enter Title to search : ");
        scanf("%s", dumpchar);
        //Search Engine Making
        //char dumpchar
        **printing(search(name,dumpchar));**

    }else if(select_search==2){

        printf("Enter Author to search : ");
        scanf("%s", &dumpchar);
        printing(search(author,dumpchar));
    }else if(select_search==3){

        printf("Enter Publisher to search : ");
        scanf("%s", &dumpchar);
        printing(search(publisher,dumpchar));
    }else{
        break;
    }

    return 1;

    printf("Succeed Saved in Directory %d \n",i);
}


int search(char (*text1)[30], char *text2)
{
    int search_i=0;
    int search_j=0;
    while(*text1){
        if(*text2==*text1){
            while(*text2=*text1){
            text2++;
            text1++;
            search_j++;
            if(*text2==NULL){
                return search_i;
            }   
            }
        text2=text2-search_j;
        text1=text1-search_j;   
        }
        text1++;
        search_i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Whenever I try to pass the two parameters in search function,

this error occurs, please help me adjust this error.

program Indicates this part causing error : printing(search(name,dumpchar));

says [Error] cannot convert 'char (*)[30]' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'int search(char*, char*)'

Please someone help !!!

Comment: In any case the function is invalid and does not make sense.:)

Comment: Your search functions does ` while(*text2=*text1)`, which copies characters from text1 to text2, perhaps you meant using == there.

Comment: Trust the error: `cannot convert 'char ()[30]' to 'char' for argument '1' to 'int search(char*, char*)'`. There has been a lot of effort put into compiler error messages over the past 20 years to provide a concise description of exactly what the problem is. They look cryptic at first, but if you just *slow-down* and *think* about what the compiler is trying to tell you, 99 times out of 100, it is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you SO much I was bit frustrated not carefully paying attention. But Thanks a looooott !!!

Answer (score 1):

The prototype declaration

```
int search(char *text1, char *text2);
```

is wrong and doesn't match to the function definition.

Use correct one:

```
int search(char (*text1)[30], char *text2);
```

Also note that `scanf("%s", &dumpchar);` invokes *undefined behavior* by passing pointer to object having wrong type to `scanf()`. Use `scanf("%s", dumpchar);` just as you did in a previous line. `scanf("%29s", dumpchar);` is better because the maximum length is spcified to avoid buffer overrun.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `name` is an array of arrays of `char`, i.e. it's an array of strings. The `search` function doesn't accept an array of strings as its first argument, just a single string (pointer to `char`).

At least that's how you *declared* the `search` function. You will also get an error because the definition of the function doesn't match the declaration.

To fix the problem make the declaration match the definition.